# about thread exit

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I found a problem in my win32 program. When I exit the program, I saw many log in output like below:

---

The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xbec) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x4c0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x97c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xe10) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x5f0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xfc0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xdc0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

---

I don't know if these are normal behaviour. Is anyone can tell me what's happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've started 6 threads (in addition to the default one) it's perfectly normal. If you've used something like a thread pool, you may have created those implicitly, perhaps without even being aware of it.

Bottom line: unless you're *quite* sure your code is single threaded, it's probably entirely normal.

Answer (score 2):

When you exit the program all threads should be torn down. Why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: My program run and exit without any problem. I am just interest in the output logs. So I know they are normal behavoirs, right? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Right. All threads are torn down whether your program exits gracefully or not: i.e. even if you kill it via Task Manager, you should still see similar output (though Task Manager may use a different exit code).